# Powershell how to run a program and waiting in a remote session

Tags: powershell

I have a command line program that listen to a tcp port until user type Q to exist. It works fine in local powershell window. But when I try to run it on another machine using powershell remote session, it just starts and quit. Is there a way to keep it running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remote script runs in a PowerShell that never becomes visible so AFAICT it doesn't even got a console handle by which to handle reading keyboard input.

You can take a look at the SysInternals utility - `psexec`.  From my testing, that utility works for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I do not really need interaction. I am good as long as it is running there, like in local, not start and close immediately.

Comment: Is there a command line option for that utility to tell it not to seek user input?  In my testing, a remote session seems to just skip over input operations like Console.Read/ReadLine() and outright errors on Console.ReadKey().

Comment: I am using Console.ReadLine() to check the inputs. I can modify the C# program. How to keep it running with out that trick?

Comment: It doesn't look like this is doable in a console exe running under remoting:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ce728e28-31c4-43fb-9bcc-bcaa2294107b/helphow-to-input-in-powershell-remote?forum=winserverpowershell  Interestingly, Read-Host in a script does work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure you have Powershell 3 or higher since it adds support for detached sessions/background jobs.
2. Use a Remote Disconnected Session, described on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj149006%28v=wps.620%29.aspx)

Comment: Looks like I am using 2.0

Comment: @Ryan is [upgrading to 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595) a option?